# How do I change keys in JAVA SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I am building a Server and Client that uses TLS Channel and SEED Algorithm for Data Encryption.

I've gone through documents about SSL Connection and wondering when I should exchange the key for the data encryption.

I can see that there are good SSL Class for JAVA so i can open SSL channel easily with selected certificate.

My first question is when i should exchange secret key for encryption. after the Certificate exchange, and ssl socket acception, is it safe to just send key through the channel? or are there other ways to do this?

Second Question is is there any way to manage certificates for each client? cuz seems like the certificate itself is included in the ssl socket.

Thank you

Comment: Why? If you're using TLS you already have encryption, key exchange, certificate exchange, ... And certificates are not 'included in the SSL socket', whatever that means. I suggest you do some more reading. Start with the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: What I really want to do is whether there is actual secure connected channel or not, I want to encrypt my data for my requirements. What I am exactly wondering is... the possibility of making certificate or some kind of passworded file where I can inject my secret key of data encryption(SEED, ARIA Algorithm)